# An advice for a design between parent and child classes?

Tags: java, class, parent-child, simulation

I'm working on a physics simulation.

I have an `ArrayList` that holds all the objects in my simulation. I have a parent class: `Shape`, and two child classes: `Circle` and `Rectangle`.

The parent class, of course, doesn't have a `draw()` method but each of the child classes does. Therefore, when I'm looping trough the list to draw each element, it doesn't allow me because there isn't a `draw()` method in the `Shape` class (as I'm defining the list as `ArrayList<Shape>`, and adding each new element with a child class instance).

Is there a way to resolve this problem in a good and neat way?

Comment: You want an `abstract` method.

Comment: I tried to define the shapes class as abstract and then add the abstract method draw, but still didn't work @SLaks

Comment: if you are really creating a Circle object in the ArrayList then it will work just fine

Comment: it works now, thanks!

Comment: I'm very puzzled on how this question received 5 upvotes, since it has been answered 1000 times in ANY base tutorial on Java and inheritance of these last 20 years. And more, quite all books treat exactly the Shape example, talking about abstract methods. Boh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The neatest way to move forward is to use interfaces.

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    @Override
    public void draw() { // draw rect }
}

public class Circle implements Shape {
    @Override
    public void draw() { // draw circle }
}
```

If you want Shape to share some other logic with it's children you can create an AbstractShape class implementing Shape with any additional code and extend the child classes using this abstract class.

Comment: Since this interface declares only a `draw()` method, I would name the interface `Drawable`, instead of `Shape`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld yes that would be better. Conventionally interfaces should be names after adjectives.

Answer (score 4):

it seems to provide an abstract method for the `Shape` class where all subclasses share a common behaviour is best for the task at hand.

Consider this is the `Shape` class:

```
public abstract class Shapes{
    public abstract void Draw();
}
```

the `Rectangle` class:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shapes{
    public void Draw(){
        System.out.println("Rectangle");
    }
}
```

the `Circle` class:

```
public class Circle extends Shapes{
    public void Draw(){
        System.out.println("Circle");
    }
}
```

now considering that both `Circle` and `Rectangle` are of type `Shape`, you can create objects of type `Circle` or/and `Rectangle`, add them to the ArrayList, iterate over it, and invoke the `Draw()` method on each object like so:

```
ArrayList<Shapes> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add(new Circle());
shapes.add(new Rectangle());
shapes.forEach(Shapes::Draw);
```

result when `Draw()` method is invoked on each object:

```
Circle
Rectangle
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

A class called Shapes that has a field for List<**Shape**>
**Shape** is an interface holding the method draw() getArea() or any others.
Have as many classes implementing **Shape**, circle, rectangle, square etc.